# Как установить библиотеку дискорд в визуал студио коде на мак бук?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Программирую на визуал студио коде у меня проблем т.к у меня мак бук я не могу установить библиотеку дискорд через повер шел и цмд. Как это сделать по другому?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите в вопрос скриншоты с проблемой или сообщения об ошибках (для этого нажмите [edit])

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.exe` на Mac'e нет, но там есть терминал с командной оболочкой ZSH

Сначала [открываем терминал](https://support.apple.com/ru-ru/guide/terminal/apd5265185d-f365-44cb-8b09-71a064a42125/mac#:%7E:text=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0,%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%C2%AB%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%C2%BB.).

Потом устанавливаем nuget, если его нет

```
brew install nuget
```

Потом устанавливаем нужный пакет.
В общем виде синтаксис будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
nuget install <packageID | configFilePath> -Version <version>
```

Я не уверен в том, какой конкретно пакет Вам необходим, но
Для примера:

```
nuget install Discord.Net -Version 3.10.0
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Discord.Net